# PHP Upload script is not posting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP image upload script. The uploading part of the script is working, but when I try to upload the $newname of the image to the database it is not working. I dont get any error or something. It is just dont doing anything.

Here is my script

```
<?php

//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file is an image by checking the extension. 
function getExtension($str) {
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error found) and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures. If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
$errors=0;

//checks if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{

//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

//if it is not empty
if ($image) 
{

//get the original name of the file from the clients machine
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

//get the extension of the file in a lower case format
$extension = getExtension($filename);
$extension = strtolower($extension);

//if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not upload the file, otherwize we will do more tests
if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
{

//print error message
echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
$errors=1;
}
else
{

//get the size of the image in bytes
//$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
$size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
$errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;

//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;

//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
$errors=1;
}}}}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
{
echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully!</h1>";

session_start(); 

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET logo='" . $newname . "' WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['USER_ID'] ."'";

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for `$sql = "UPDATE users SET...`

You never queried.

SooOoooo...

`$sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET ...");`

and check for errors on PHP and MySQL and that the session array does have a value and that the column is long enough to hold the data.

If (and for example) `WHERE user_id=1";` works, then your session array is empty and was never set.

You may also be outputting before header, so place `session_start();` at the top of your script. Which is what's going on here. Your code puts on the brakes as soon as it hits starting the session and failed on you *silently*.

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: `echo`'ing before starting session ;-) *boooooooooom*